# Groupby (group-by, group by) on empty Pandas dataframe (data-frame, data frame) behavior

Tags: sql, pandas, group-by, aggregate, dataframe

When attempting to do a groupby on a dataframe that includes columns that have datatypes that can not be aggregated, those columns are not returned in the groupby. That seems OK, but here is where it is causing me problems. When I load the results of an SQL query into a dataframe, if the result of that SQL query is empty, I get a dataframe with default values that are objects. Objects can't be aggregated, so when I do a groupby, I get an empty dataframe returned that has no columns. When I try to perform operations on that dataframe, I get an error saying that the columns I'm looking for aren't there.

Sample code:

```
my_query = '''
select day_of_week, revenue, expenses
from finance
'''

df = pd.read_sql(my_query, my_connection) # gives me an empty dataframe of object types

df = df.groupby('day_of_week').sum().reset_index() # returns empty df with no columns

profit = df.revenue - df.expenses # error
```

At the 'profit' line I get an error saying that "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'revenue'" because that column isn't returned in the groupby.

If my SQL query returns a blank dataframe I would want 'profit' to be null or something. Should there be an option with groupby to return columns of null values (or something) if those columns can't be aggregated? I think there should be.

As a work-around is there a way to get my dataframe to be initialized with floats instead of objects so that the rest of my code after the groupby doesn't cause an error?

Or maybe even SQL can return 0s instead of nothing?

EDIT: adding some code that you can run to reproduce the issue

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

finance = ()

# uncomment to load the table with data: won't get the error
# finance = (
#     (2, 132, 65),
#     (6, 142, 86),
#     (3, 183, 34),
#     (3, 147, 46)
# )

con = lite.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS finance")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE finance(day_of_week INT, revenue FLOAT, expenses FLOAT)")
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO finance VALUES(?, ?, ?)", finance)

my_query = '''
    SELECT *
    FROM finance
    '''

df = pd.read_sql(my_query, con)

df_gb = df.groupby('day_of_week').sum().reset_index()

profit = df_gb.revenue - df_gb.expenses # AttributeError thrown here
```

I think the Pandas `read_sql` function should create empty columns of the same type as the SQL table. I also think that the `groupby` function should have a parameter, maybe `drop_non_agg` that is by default `False`. Non-aggregatable columns could be filled with null values.

Do either of these solutions exist right now?

Comment: Maybe put some sort of logic above the groupby. if df.count() == 0: profit = 0 else: groupby, etc

Comment: Thanks DataSwede, that's an OK workaround, but I feel that shouldn't have to be done. I would really like for Pandas to handle this situation.

Comment: What pandas version?  I just tried on 0.14.1 with a manually created DataFrame and profit was created as an empty Series without error.

Comment: chrisb, yes, with a manually created DataFrame it does work for me as well. It appears that when you create an empty DataFrame manually, the default datatype for each column is a float. However, when it is created from SQL results, the default is 'object'. I'm not sure why that is or how to change that.